# Classes from other modules throw error when initiating - Python

Tags: python

I have a really annoying problem, I have 3 python files: my doctree looks like this:

```
/index.py
/system [dir]
    system/system.py
    system/path.py
    system/__init__.py
```

**File contents:**

index.py:

```
import system.system

input_str = ""
command = ""

sys = System()
path = sys.Path()

def loop():
    global path, input_str

    input_str = raw_input(path.val + " > ")

    format_str(input_str)


def format_str(input_str):
    global command
    command = ""

    for i in range(len(input_str)):
        if (input_str[i] == " "):
            break
        else:
            command += input_str[i]

    command = command.lower()

    if (command == "exit"):
        exit()
    else:
        interpret()

def interpret():
    global command
    if (command == "cd"):
        path.changeDir()

loop()
```

system.py:

```
class System:
    version = "0.1.0b"
    inf = ""

    def __init__(self):
        self.inf = open("../inf.txt").read()

    def inf():
        print version
```

path.py:

```
import system

class Path(system.System):
    val = "/"
    path = Path()

    def __init__(startDir):
        global val
        val = startDir

    def getPath():
        print val
```

basically, All I want to do is initiate the system class as a variable called sys and extend the Path class from System (so that it becomes a subclass) and have those two files be in a separate dir so that is just neater, now when I import system.system, I assume that I am importing the system module in the system package, but then I call System() and get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "index.py", line 6, in <module>
        sys = System()
NameError: name 'System' is not defined
```

and I get the same error when I remove the last `.system` from the import statement and when I import both modules. anyway, it's a big mess and I have no idea how to approach it, I've started by Googling Python classes, and it seems I'm doing everything correctly, but I get these errors, please help.

- regards Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not importing the `System` class correctly on `index.py`.

You should do:

```
from system.system import System
```

instead of

```
import system.system
```

Comment: in case you saw my last coment, please disregard, your advice was very helpful and now executes the program without errors, thankyou for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it's correct.

Comment: My I just ask, how come did the other method not work?

Comment: That kind of import doesn't work in Python. Another option would be:

    import system.system.System
    ...
    sys = system.system.System()